# Форматирование делает отступ перед тегом head, как убрать это поведение?

Tags: visual-studio-code, форматирование, prettier, форматирование-кода

На маке при форматировании(Option+Shift+F) между "" и "" пропускается строчка, как убрать это поведение?
На новом ноутбуке я скачал VsCode(настройки дефолтные)
Поведение было таким же, после этого поставил свои расширения, включая Prettier, поведение не поменялось
Пробовал менять настройки, до истины не дошел

[image: Скрины до и после форматирования]